# AngularJS with TypeScript: unit testing services with Jasmine / Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, bdd, karma-jasmine, typescript-typings

I'm looking for AngularJS with TypeScript unit testing services with Jasmine / Karma tutorials, from scratch.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance.